# When using fastlane frameit for screenshots, how do you stack the title and keyword text?

Tags: ios, app-store, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot, frameit

I'm generating app store screenshots using fastlane frameit. How do you stack the keyword on top of the title like in the image below?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue recently.

First of all, update to the latest version of fastlane using

```
sudo gem update fastlane
```

Next, follow instructions [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/frameit#usage):

Create Framefile.json in your screenshots directory (which was created by snapshot if you use it). Mine looks like this:

```
    {
      "default": {
        "keyword": {
          "font": "./fonts/SFText-Heavy.otf",
          "color": "#76A43B"
        },
        "title": {
          "font": "./fonts/SFText-Regular.otf",
          "color": "#FFFFFF"
        },
        "background": "./background.jpg",
        "padding": 50,
        "stack_title" : true,
        "show_complete_frame": false
      },
      "data": [
        {"filter":"Explore"},
        {"filter":"Search"},
        {"filter":"RecipeCard"},
        {"filter":"Groceries"},
        {"filter":"Favourites"}
      ]
    }
```

Note that "stack_title" is set to true.

Also you must provide a background picture, title.strings and keyword.strings (for each locale) for frameit to do its job.

Next you just launch frameit in your screenshots directory:

```
fastlane frameit
```

If you have any questions about strings files or something else, I strongly recommend you to visit frameit github page I've linked above. They have a very nice example there.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here because it took me an embarrassing amount of time to realize.

Since v 2.4.0 you can include `\n` in your string to have it go to the next line...

https://github.com/fastlane-old/frameit/releases/tag/2.4.0